# Passing Bluetooth device to a service, null getParcelableExtra

Tags: android, android-intent, null, bluetooth, android-service

I am trying to maintain bluetooth connection when the screen is off. So I created an app that you can discover bluetooth devices around and choose from list. Then pass the chosen bluetooth device to backgroundService class which will handle the rest.But I am getting null pointer when I try to get device from intent. Any help will be appreciated.

Here is my code segments

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    if(btAdapter.isDiscovering()){
        btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    }
    if(listAdapter.getItem(arg2).contains("Paired")){

        BluetoothDevice selectedDevice = devices.get(arg2);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this,backgroundService.class);
        if(selectedDevice == null)
            Log.i(backgroundService.EXTRA_MESSAGE, "I am telling you it is null");
        intent.putExtra(backgroundService.EXTRA_MESSAGE, (Parcelable)selectedDevice);
        startService(intent);
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "device is not paired", 0).show();
    }

}
```

I also populate devices as follows

```
 receiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            if(action.equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND)){
                Log.i("onReceive", "ACTION_FOUND");
                BluetoothDevice d = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                String s = "Not Paired";
                devices.add(d);
                for(int a = 0; a < pairedDevices.size(); a++){
                    if(d.getName().equals(pairedDevices.get(a).getName())){
                        //append 
                        s = "Paired";
                        break;
                    }
                }
                listAdapter.add(d.getName()+"("+s+")\n"+ d.getAddress());
            }
```

So devices list must already have parcelable devices. I am getting null device from following code

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i(EXTRA_MESSAGE,"onStartCommand");


    BluetoothDevice selectedDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
    if(selectedDevice == null)
    {Log.i(EXTRA_MESSAGE,"null it is "); return -1;}
    connect = new ConnectThread(selectedDevice);
    connect.start();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
BluetoothDevice selectedDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
```

To this:

```
BluetoothDevice selectedDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: I actually first tried without casting. Still it doesn't work.

Comment: you dont need to do casting at all. BluetoothDevice is Parcelable.

Comment: I removed casting. Problem continues.

Comment: did you put the correct name to read parcelable out from extra? see my updated answer, its changed. refresh your page.

Comment: yes it is 
`BluetoothDevice selectedDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);`

Comment: where `EXTRA_MESSAGE` come from?

Comment: @Jansebastian it could be any string. I just used the same variable name as mentioned by OP in the provided code.